# Include First Argument in va_list object

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

Is it possible to include the first argument of a function within a va_list? I want to pass the arguments from one function to another function.

```
int main(){
    test(1,2,3,4,5,-1);
}

void test(int firstArg, ...){
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, firstArg);
    passFunction(va);
}

void passFunction(va_list va){
    int x;    
    while((x = va_arg(ap,int))!=-1){
        cout << x << endl;  
    }
}
```

Output I Want:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Actual Output:

```
2
3
4
5
```

Is there any way to achieve this without explicitly passing the first argument to the function?

Comment: If you have variadic templates available, I suggest using those instead.

Comment: I can't use them, the arguments of the test function must be compatible with C as I have a C function calling them.

Comment: Why complicate the post with tag C++ and `cout << x << endl;`?  Suggest removing C++ tag and using `printf("%d\n", x);`

Comment: @chux C and C++ have different rules regarding variadic functions, so using the right tag according to what compiler is in use is important

Comment: @M.M Agreed.  Good to see the post is now only of 1 language.

Comment: Why not manually pass the int first?  Second, what are your exact performance requirements?  What code, exactly, can be changed?

Comment: Variadic templates and std::bind might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it recently and thought I would share my solution.  This answer should work regardless of the compiler, but adds a little more code.  I use the first parameter in the while statement but I don't call va_arg() until I've consumed the first parameter.

```
 main () {
        test( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1 );
    }

void passFunction( int one, va_list va )
{
    int x = one;
    va_list va_copy;
   
    va_copy( va_copy, va );
    while (x != -1)
    {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
        x = va_arg( va_copy, int );        
    }
    va_end( va_copy );
}

void test( int one, ... ) const
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va,one);
    passFunction( one, va );
    va_end(va);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`va_start()` requires a fixed parameter and initializes the `va_list` to the *next* parameter following the specified parameter.  Since your function only has one fixed parameter, there is no option to include it in the `va_list` using the stock `va_start()` because there is no fixed parameter in front of it.

In 32-bit only (64-bit is MUCH more complex), you can copy your compiler's source code for `va_start()` from `varargs.h` or `stdargs.h` (or equivalent code) into your own source file and then tweak it to initialize the `va_arg` with the address of the specified parameter itself rather than the address that follows it.

For example, in C++Builder, `va_start()` is defined as:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define va_start(ap, parmN) ((void)((ap) = (std::va_list)((char _FAR *)(&parmN)+__size(parmN))))
#else
#define va_start(ap, parmN) ((void)((ap) = (va_list)((char _FAR *)(&parmN)+__size(parmN))))
#endif
```

So you would just remove the `+__size(parmN)` portion:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define my_va_start(ap, parmN) ((void)((ap) = (std::va_list)((char _FAR *)(&parmN))))
#else
#define my_va_start(ap, parmN) ((void)((ap) = (va_list)((char _FAR *)(&parmN))))
#endif
```

In Visual Studio, `va_start()` is defined as:

```
#define _crt_va_start(ap,v)  ( ap = (va_list)_ADDRESSOF(v) + _INSIZEOF(v) )
#define va_start _crt_va_start
```

So you would just remove the `+ _INSIZEOF(v)` portion:

```
#define my_va_start(ap,v)  ( ap = (va_list)_ADDRESSOF(v) )
```

GCC actually uses compiler intrinsic functions instead of macros, so you probably can't get its `va_start()` source, but the generated code should be similar since the `cdecl` calling convention (the only calling convention that supports variadic parameters in 32bit) is fairly standardized across compilers.

Either way, the code generated by the preprocessor will end up roughly the same, so you could just code it directly, if it is compatible with your compiler:

```
void test(int firstArg, ...){
    va_list va = (va_list) &firstArg;
    passFunction(va);
}
```

Comment: It may be a better idea to have a dummy internal function which will add a dummy parameter and make the call to `passFunction` rather than changing va_start.

Comment: @user1952500: Easier said then done, since a variadic function cannot directly call another variadic function, the dummy function would have to resort to inline assembly to manipulate the call stack in order to inject the dummy parameter correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau very interesting! Thanks for the clarification. If the OP only wants to hide the ugliness of the static parameter from the _caller_ of the function, could we not have something like:
#define passFunction(x) passfunction_internal(5, x)

and implement:
void passfunction_internal(va_list va) in exactly the same way as mentioned above ?

Comment: Note that on Mac OS X, there is no file `<stdarg.h>` to scrutinize — at least, not in `/usr/include`.  GCC 6.1.0 has them buried under the directory it is installed in (`./include/c++/6.1.0/tr1/stdarg.h` and `./lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0/6.1.0/include/stdarg.h`; the install directory on my machine happens to be `/opt/gcc/v6.1.0` but that's not a standard location).  And XCode (7.3.0) buried it out in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.3.0/include/stdarg.h`.

Comment: @user1952500: that does not accomplish the OP's desired goal of including the `firstArg` parameter of `test()` into the `va_list` that is passed to `passFunction()`.  All you are doing is making `passFunction()` have an extra hidden parameter in addition to the original `va_list` that `test()` creates without `firstArg` in it. `passfunction_internal(5, x)` would require `passfunction_internal()` to be defined as `void passfunction_internal(int firstArg, va_list va)`, the `5` does not get injected into the `va_list`.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the clarifications @RemyLebeau!

Comment: How can I find how va_start is defined in gcc?

Comment: AFAIK, GCC actually uses compiler intrinsic functions, not macros. See [17.10 Implementing the Varargs Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Varargs.html).